# Custom grouping by months with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to group monthly cash flows from a pandas dataframe on an irregular basis: for instance, at the end of months whose index is in [4, 9, 12].
I have been messing around with pd.groupby() and pd.resample() but can't figure out a syntax that works.

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

index = pd.date_range(dt.datetime(2015, 1, 1), periods=12, freq='M')
data = (10 * np.random.rand(12)).round()
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index = index, columns = ['A'])

print df
```

Basically, from a list [4, 9, 12], I am looking for a syntax that would sum together the months 1-4, 5-9 and 10-12. For instance, from the column A below, I would like to get either the column B or C with a running-sum ending on these given months:

```
            A  B   C
2015-01-31  9  9   0
2015-02-28  7  16  0
2015-03-31  5  21  0
2015-04-30  4  25  25
2015-05-31  6  6   0
2015-06-30  8  14  0
2015-07-31  2  16  0
2015-08-31  7  23  0
2015-09-30  0  23  23
2015-10-31  5  5   0
2015-11-30  5  10  0
2015-12-31  8  18  18
```

Thank you for your help!

Jean

Comment: How is column B derived from column A?

Comment: Just edited my post to make it clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using some string formatting to get the index, but works for any combination of months (as long as the first month is explicitly included).

It avoids to loop over the full Pandas dataframe, looping over the required months only.

```
year = 2015                                                                      
months = [1, 4, 9, 12]                                                               
for num, month in enumerate(months[:-1]):                                        
    csum = df['{0}-{1}'.format(year, month):'{0}-{1}'.format(                    
        year,months[num+1]-1)].A.sum()                                           
    df.loc['{0}-{1}'.format(year,months[num+1]), 'B'] = csum                   

print(df)

            A   B                                                                 
2015-01-31  5 NaN
2015-02-28  1 NaN
2015-03-31  3 NaN
2015-04-30  7   9
2015-05-31  6 NaN
2015-06-30  9 NaN
2015-07-31  4 NaN
2015-08-31  4 NaN
2015-09-30  9  30
2015-10-31  3 NaN
2015-11-30  0 NaN
2015-12-31  9  12
```

Answer (score 0):

The ugly and slow way, and `index` and `i` are probably not the best variable names either...

Can probably be improved using `map` or `apply`.

```
df['B'] = 0
for index, i in enumerate(df.index):
    if i.month in [4, 9, 12]:
        df['B'][i] = sum(df['A'][index - 3:index + 1].tolist())
print df

            A   B
2015-01-31  9   0
2015-02-28  8   0
2015-03-31  4   0
2015-04-30  7  28
2015-05-31  4   0
2015-06-30  4   0
2015-07-31  2   0
2015-08-31  5   0
2015-09-30  8  19
2015-10-31  5   0
2015-11-30  0   0
2015-12-31  4  17
```

Comment: Thanks but I would expect col B to have zeros everywhere except on months 4 (28), 9 (23) and 12 (9), this is not what gives your formula. I edited my post if my first question was not clear enough. –